# Converting masked currency string using Decimal.TryParse

Tags: c#, decimal, cultureinfo

I'm having issue converting this string to a decimal. I tried to follow the documentation here with no luck: [Decimal.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx)

```
string stringVal = "-(3434343434.00)";

NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
    NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

decimal value;
bool parseSuccess = decimal.TryParse(stringVal, style, culture, out value);
```

parseSuccess is returning false.

Comment: `decimal.TryParse` is not an expression evaluator. Give it a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both `()` and a `-` sign in your string. This is incorrect and is why your string doesn't parse.

See the documentations for `AllowParentheses`:

> **AllowParentheses**: Indicates that the numeric string can have one pair of parentheses enclosing the number. The parentheses indicate that the string to be parsed represents a negative number.

Comment: Thanks! The creation of the sign and the parenthesis I now realize is a bug in Telerik's RadMaskedEditBox control, which is where I was getting the string.

Answer (score 4):

I think a - sign and parenthesis at the same time is not valid.  -3434343434.00 is fine as is (3434343434.00) but -(3434343434.00) is not valid.  -(3434343434.00) does not really make sense it is using 2 different methods to indicate a negative and as such is a bit redundant.